# Solving the recurrence with $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n = \left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)a_{n-1} + 2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can anyone here help me to solve this recurrence relation?

> $$a_0 = 0,\quad a_n = \left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)a_{n-1} + 2, \quad n > 0$$

I've tried lots of ways to solve it, unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ways like what?

Comment: Have you tried calculating it in a spreadsheet?  That will give you a hypothesis that you can try to validate.

Comment: I've tried to expand just the fraction $\frac{n-2}{n}$ and then I devided all terms by the result ($\frac{2}{n(n-1)}$)... however I got a loop..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $n>1$, we have
$$a_n=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n(n-1)}a_{n-1}+2,$$
$$n(n-1)a_n=(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-1}+2n(n-1),$$
let $b_n=n(n-1)a_n$ and it is not hard to solve $b_n$ then get $a_n$.